# 2D vector field with a polygonal mask: nearest vertex to any given point

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy

I'm trying to create a 2D vector field, with a polygonal "mask" applied such that the angles and values at every point are a function of their distance from the nearest vertex of that polygon.

I guessed that `scipy.interpolate` might have what I need, but I could use some guidance.

So far I can create a polygon with matplotlib, get its vertices, and use them to create an interpolator, but after that point I have no idea what I'm doing.

Here's what the relevant psuedocode should look like, I think:

```
for point in all_points:
    nearest = NearestPoint(polygon_vertices, point)
    value = point - nearest
    angle = Angle(nearest, point)
```

The hardest part would be calculating the nearest vertex of the polygon for any given coordinate: but there must be a numpy/scipy function for this...

Here's what I've got so far:

```py
def CircleVertices():
    circ = plt.Circle((0.5, 0.5), radius=0.4, edgecolor='b', facecolor='None')
    return circ.get_path().vertices

def NearestNeighborInterpolate():
    vertices = CircleVertices()
    x, y = vertices[:,0], vertices[:,1]
    z = [np.hypot(x, y) for x,y in vertices]

    X = np.linspace(min(x)-0.5, max(x)+0.5, num=100)
    Y = np.linspace(min(y)-0.5, max(y)+0.5, num=100)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    interp = scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
    Z = interp(X, Y)

    plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, shading='auto')
    plt.plot(x, y, "ok", label="input point")

    plt.legend()
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.show()

def GriddataInterpolate():
    vertices = CircleVertices()
    x, y = vertices[:,0], vertices[:,1]

    xx = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
    yy = np.linspace(-1, 1, 20)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

    u = [np.hypot(x, y) for x,y in vertices]
    v = [0.5 for _ in x]

    u_interp = scipy.interpolate.griddata(vertices, u, (xx, yy), method='linear')
    v_interp = scipy.interpolate.griddata(vertices, v, (xx, yy), method='linear')

    plt.quiver(xx, yy, u_interp, v_interp)
    plt.show()
```

Which produces these two graphs:

[nearest neighbor circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3nBB.png)

[grid data interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPj2v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NearestNDInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html)

Modifying a bit the example in the documentation

```py
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()
x = rng.random(10) - 0.5
y = rng.random(10) - 0.5
# in 2D you can represent the point as a complex number
z = x + 1j * y 
X = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 256)
Y = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 256)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)  # 2D grid for interpolation
interp = NearestNDInterpolator(list(zip(x, y)), z)
Z = interp(X, Y)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4.5))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, abs(Z - (X + 1j*Y)), shading='auto')
plt.plot(x, y, "ok", label="input point")
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Distance')
plt.axis("equal")

plt.subplot(122)
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, (180 / np.pi) * np.angle((X + 1j*Y) - Z), shading='auto')
plt.plot(x, y, "ok", label="input point")
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Angle')
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()

plt.show()
```

you have this
[image: result]